# R in conda environment displays version 3.6.1 rather than 4.1.3

Tags: python, r, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

[image: conda-forge screenshot]

On my anaconda prompt, using these conda-forge packages to install r-base, i was expecting that when creating the environment i'll see r-base version 4.1.3 but instead it displays that the highest version of r available on my windows is version 3.6.1 as in the second screenshot. Please i'll need some help or pointers to where i might have gotten it wrong [image: screenshot of anaconda environment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first screenshot is from conda-forge, which is a repository that is not being searched by default. The highest available version in the default repositories is 3.6. You need to add conda-forge as a channel to the environment, but I'm not sure how that works in the GUI. In the anaconda prompt you can do this

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

in an activated environment.

Also `r` and `r-base` are different packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So after pasting the code you provided on anaconda prompt, it didn't return  any anything significant, checked anaconda navigator GUI and discovered that  next to the channels option in the environment page, 'update index' button displayed, clicked on it and it update everything and i have r version 4.1.3 in my environment. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sure, no problem! If this helped you solve your problem please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: "*`r` and `r-base` are different packages*" - technically yes, but in their essence they're both are about controlling the R version. Only difference is the `r` package is a metapackage that adds a few extra defaults packages (`r-recommended`) to the R installation.

Comment: Yes, but this is about technicalities. They don't follow the same version numbers (one is more fine-grained), so confusion about available versions might arise under the assumption that they're the same package.